# Duda acerca de declaracion de getter en Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Tengo el siguiente código

```
val Context.database : SQLiteHelper get() = SQLiteHelper.getInstance(applicationContext)
```

Estoy estudiando `android`, con `kotlin`, nunca había visto la siguiente sintaxis:

```
val Context.database
```

Por lo que entiendo esta declarando un `getter` que se llama `database` cuyo tipo a retornar es lo que devuelve `getInstance` de `SQLiteHelper`

Pero no entiendo para que usa el operador `.` al declarar `database` es decir no entiendo el porque `Context` y después `database`.

Es como en `javascript` y a la clase `Context` en este caso le estamos agregando una propiedad nueva dinamicamente con el `.` o el funcionamiento es similar, podrían explicarme exactamente que ocurre?

También en el código que estoy estudiando tengo esta declaración parecida

```
val androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.database: SQLiteHelper get() = SQLiteHelper.getInstance(activity!!.applicationContext)
```

Los `getter` están declarados afuera de una clase, están de forma global.

Comment: No sé mucho de android ni anko, pero lo que está ocurriendo ahí es que estás declarándole una variable de extensión a la clase `Context` llamada `database`. Es decir, cualquier clase que herede de `Context` tendrá esa propiedad que al llamarla te devolverá, en este caso, una instancia de `SQLiteHelper`.

Answer (score 0):

puntualmente para crear una variable en Kotlin lleva la siguiente estructura
var o val = para definir si una variable es inmutable o mutable
Context.database = el tipo esto define el tipo de variable en tu caso dice se una variable de tipo database que pertenece a context
SQLiteHelper get() = SQLiteHelper.getInstance(applicationContext)= y por ultimo la asignacion o valor, esto quiere decir que la instancia de sqlitehelper debe devolver un dato de tipo Context.database o si no te daria error